# How to convert more than one GridView to one XML file

Tags: c#, xml, gridview

my C# WinForms Application has 3 GridViews which I want to save in one XML file. 
For one gridview I do it like this:

```c#
DataTable dst = new Datatable();
dst = (DataTable)grdViewBGM.DataSource;
dst.TableName = "GridView";
dst.WriteXml(folderPath + String.Format("\\{0}.xml", filename), true);
```

It may be simple to solve that but I don't have a clue except for making 3 xml files which is everything but perfect. 
If someone could give me an advice that would be awesome, thanks.

The created file looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
    <GridView>
        <Genre>Wald</Genre>
        <Pfad>C:\Users\Kong\Desktop\Beards\Wald</Pfad>
        <Hotkey>1</Hotkey>
    </GridView>
    <GridView>
        <Genre>Wald Nachts</Genre>
        <Pfad>C:\Users\Kong\Desktop\Beards\Wald Nachts</Pfad>
        <Hotkey>2</Hotkey>
    </GridView>
</DocumentElement>
```

Comment: Do you actually create a file? What does the file look like? can you post its contents? Furthermore, are you sure that the dst variable has a legitimate structure when you call WriteXml?

Comment: Where is the source of the GridView.  If source is already a DataTable is may be very easy.

Comment: Yes I expanded my post for you Marc and yes jdweng the source of the GridView is actually in a DataTable :)

Comment: If that is an accurate representation of your data, you shouldn't really need multiple `DataGridView`'s, since each one is only one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way is to populate the `Tables` collection of a `DataSet`.  It has a method to write to xml.

```
void MakeXML(string fileName)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    foreach(DataGridView dgv in this.Controls.OfType<DataGridView>())
    {
        ds.Tables.Add((DataTable)dgv.DataSource);
    }
    ds.WriteXml(fileName);
}
```

If the `DataGridView`'s aren't in the current form(`this`), use the name of whichever control contains them.  If they are spread out, keep a global `List<DataGridView>` that you add to each time a `DataGridView` is created, then use that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but 'this.Controls.OfType<DataGridView>()'  is empty :^(

Comment: @KommissarKong - I added more explanation to my answer.

Comment: I get your point but the gridviews should be available in THIS. When I ask for this.Controls.OfType<Button>()' I get every button in my Form, but it doesn't work with DataGridView although they're on the same Form. Thanks btw for bearing with me till now

Comment: @KommissarKong - This would suggest to me that they are actually in a different control, a `TabControl` perhaps?  Did you see my other comment about needing multiple `DataGridView`'s?  If you can organize your data to use one `DataGridView`, the rest of this might be moot.